# .log file doesn't always overwrite via ftp

Tags: php, logging, ftp

I have a .log file I've been attempting to log to via php. Writing to it via php seems to be working sporadically for the same lines of code. In addition I also occasionally try to overwriting the file via ftp, this also only works sporadically. Can any one suggest what might be causing this behavior.

Here is a line of php demonstrating how I am writing to the file via php:

```
file_put_contents('aggregation5',"\r\ntest line",FILE_APPEND);
```

Update:

Everything works as expected if I don't use the .log extension. Is this an improper use of a .log file?

Comment: Lacks info: exactly how are you writing to the file (are you using error_log)? Consider including the source of the function actually writing to the file.

Comment: I added a line showing how I'm writing via php, as far as FTP goes I'm just dragging it over in Filezilla